# will a record set derived from jsonb_to_recordset always maintain the order of the items in a JSON array

Tags: postgresql

I want to be able to retrieve a jsonb array of objects as a record set. Maintaining the order of objects is critical. Will jsonb_to_recordset always return the record set in the order of the array of objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another solution using another of Postgres' json functions: [jsonb_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html).

```
  SELECT id, (value->>'benefit')::varchar as benefit, ordinality as rank
  FROM products 
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(benefits) with ordinality
```

"with ordinality" gives you the order of each array item and allows you to do an explicit order by on that field to ensure the order remains the same.

[This stackoverflow post was very helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819025/getting-row-number-for-from-jsonb-array-elements-or-jsonb-to-recordset)

Comment: Also works with jsonb_to_recordset: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a1715731a5ba57fa7002e7be4b5570dd.

Answer (score 1):

> Will jsonb_to_recordset always return the record set in the order of the array of objects?

Maybe, maybe not — this question is based on a faulty premise, which is that a set is ordered without an explicit `ORDER BY` clause. Even if you could show that `jsonb_to_recordset` always returns the array elements in array order in every possible edge case with the version of Postgres you are using, there would be no guarantee that a future version would not change the behaviour.

In other words, even though in JSON [an array is an ordered sequence of zero or more values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214293/is-the-order-of-elements-in-a-json-list-preserved), the output of `jsonb_to_recordset` is *by definition* unordered, no matter what you see in practice, without an explicit `ORDER BY`. Of course, you may consider the risk worth taking.

One (very inefficient) way of guaranteeing the order would be to use a recursive query:

> ```
> create table tab(col jsonb);
> ```

> ```
> insert into tab(col) values ('[{"a":"1","b":"foo"}
>                               ,{"a":"2","b":"bar"}
>                               ,{"a":"3","b":"baz"}]');
> ```

> ```
> select * from jsonb_to_recordset((select col from tab)) as x(a int, b text);
> ```
>
> ```
>  a | b  
> -: | :--
>  1 | foo
>  2 | bar
>  3 | baz
> ```

> ```
> with recursive t(n) as ( values (0)
>                          union all
>                          select n+1
>                          from t 
>                          where n < jsonb_array_length((select col from tab))-1 )
> select ((select col from tab)->n->>'a')::integer a
>       ,((select col from tab)->n->>'b') b
> from t 
> order by n;
> ```
>
> ```
>  a | b  
> -: | :--
>  1 | foo
>  2 | bar
>  3 | baz
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a3899264abae657d02cd6dcc8bd02b60)*